# Accessing the 'strdup' of a static array from a different file

Tags: c, multithreading

I use the `get_sessionid()` function below from a thread function and then try to free that pointer.

```
static char sessionid[SESSIONID_LEN] = { '\0' };

static void generate_sessionid() {
  char set[] = "0123456789"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  int len;

  memset(sessionid, 0, sizeof(char) * SESSIONID_LEN);
  for (len = 0; len < SESSIONID_LEN; len++) {
    size_t index = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX*(sizeof(set) - 1);
    sessionid[len] = set[index];
  }
}

char *get_sessionid() {
  if (strlen(sessionid) == 0) generate_sessionid();
  return strdup(sessionid);
}
```

When I debug into the thread function from which I call the above `get_sessionid`, I noticed that the session id returned is not NULL, but the program crashes with `SIGABRT` immediately when I try to free that pointer. I don't double free the pointer either which can raise an abort signal. I am not sure if thread safety is an issue here.

Also the thread function is defined in a different file.

**Edit:**

I made the change as was suggested:

```
static char sessionid[SESSIONID_LEN+1] = { '\0' };
```

I still get SIGABRT after this edit.

Another thing to mention: I don't get this signal on other machines that I have but only on 1 particular machine that runs Debian Squeeze (Linux kernel: 2.6.32-5-amd64)

**Edit 2:**

From a different thread function, a segmentation fault is thrown when trying to access the pointer returned by `get_sessionid()`: `SIGSEGV`. This error is thrown on all the machines (unlike the previous error) and is reproducible.
And when I debug and try to print the value of the returned pointer in the calling thread function, I get:

```
<Address 0xfffffffffc005080 out of bounds>
```

Comment: Possibly because `sessionid` isn't nul-terminated?

Comment: Clearly, your code does not expect `sessionid[SESSIONID_LEN-1]` to be `\0`, but it is supposed to be for it to have a chance at being a valid string.

Comment: @anthony-arnold Yes, that is a mistake. I will correct that soon and post whether that indeed was the bug that caused the SIGABRT crash

Comment: Are you freeing the pointer returned from char *get_sessionid() or sessionid[]? sessionid[] isn't a pointer.

Comment: I am freeing the pointer returned by the function `get_sessionid()` from a different file.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `sessionid` as

```
static char sessionid[SESSIONID_LEN+1] = { '\0' };
```

Then after

```
for (len = 0; len < SESSIONID_LEN; len++) {
```

`sessionid` still a valid C string (a sequence of characters and a '\0'), which is required by `strdup()`.